# How to deselect the listview item click in empty space in ListView?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

When you created a listView using javafx, there are some space below when it is not full. When you click it it will have

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at assignment5$1.handle(assignment5.java:48)
at assignment5$1.handle(assignment5.java:43)
```

How do I deselect the listview item click in empty space in ListView? I do want response in empty space of the listView select area.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a `listView.setCellFactory`?

Comment: Like @kleopatra suggests. Post an example of you code. You have an ArrayOutOfBoundsException -1 what usually means that the array is empty or contains null values. So nothing is added to the list. Post your example code according to the http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve